# Android Service for WIFI detection

Tags: android

I am working on a app in which it should list all the wifi Hotspot and also when the wifi Hotspot changes the list should be refreshed and display the new list of wifi Hotspot. Searched throught ,but got no idea how to do it.

Comment: HAve you tried anything at all?

Comment: did u check wifiscanner??

Comment: Wat is wifiscanner , can you give me links to know about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
WifiManager wifi;
WifiReciever wifiReciever;
int size = 0;
List<ScanResult> results;
String[] ssidList;
String[] bssidList;
wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getString("wifi is not enabled"),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                wifiReciever = new WifiReciever();
                IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                        WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
                registerReceiver(wifiReciever, intentFilter);
                wifi.startScan();
```

**Reciever class:**

```
        class WifiReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            results = wifi.getScanResults();
            ssidList = new String[results.size()];
            bssidList = new String[results.size()];
            if (results != null && results.size() > 0) {
                unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
                for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                    Log.i("TAG", results.get(i).SSID + "     "
                            + results.get(i).BSSID);
                    ssidList[i] = results.get(i).SSID.toString();
                    bssidList[i] = results.get(i).BSSID.toString();

                }
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(SettingsActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_choose_wifi));
                builder.setItems(ssidList,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                            // do your logic
                            }
                        });
                builder.show();

            } else {
                AndyUtills.showToast(getString("No wifi available"),
                        SettingsActivity.this);
            }

        }
    }
}
```